# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with Htmlunit use

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to scrap some websites by using htmlunit 2.16. Websites content are bit heavy and having pages around 5000. I am getting Java heap space issue after some page being scrapped. I have allocated -Xms1500m and -Xmx3000m. But after running 30/45 mins it throws java out of memory. Here is my example:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38)) {
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
    webClient.getOptions().setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

    // Get 1st page Data
    HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("www.example.com");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        try {
            HtmlElement next = (HtmlElement) currentPage
                .getByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]")
                .get(0);

            currentPage = next.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavascript(10000);
            System.out.println("Got data: " + currentPage.asXml());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

As we can see i click on the next button to get the content. I have `webClient.close()`also. Can anyone faced similar kind of issue ? Does htmlunit has some memory leak ?

Comment: @SeanBright  Sorry about typo :)

Comment: @SeanBright Thanks for the edit, but we need to add finally{webClient.close();} . This is really important.

Comment: it's handled for you automatically using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: One observation here. May not be relevant to the OOM problem though. The try-catch within the for loop does not update the loop on exceptions. Imagine `next.click()` fails with an exception and `currentPage` not updated.

Comment: @neurite Yes you are right. currentpage will not updated if next.click() failed. We can optimize the code, but here i am facing issue while scrapping.

Comment: Is this issue resolved, I am getting same OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space with versrion 2.17

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that all the pages are still stored in the history.

I disable the browsing history this way:

```
    try {
        final History window = webClient.getWebWindows().get(0).getHistory();
        final Field f = window.getClass().getDeclaredField("ignoreNewPages_"); //NoSuchFieldException
        f.setAccessible(true);
        ((ThreadLocal<Boolean>) f.get(window)).set(Boolean.TRUE);
        LOGGER.debug("_dbff772d4d_ disabled history of Webclient");
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("_66461112f7_ Can't disable history of Webclient");
    }
```

I got the idea from 
[how-to-limit-htmlunits-history-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849425/how-to-limit-htmlunits-history-size)

---

These configurations are not related to your problem, but where useful in my projects:

```
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(JAVASCRIPT_TIMOUT);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(WEB_TIMEOUT);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); 
    webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
    webClient.setRefreshHandler(new WaitingRefreshHandler(REFRESH_HANDLER_WAIT_LIMIT));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the latest version of HtmlUnit. We have fixed many memory issues inbetween. At least 2.23 hast some fixes regarding history.
Additionally you can now control the history size.